# resetCancelNextUpFlag NullPointerException in viewpager touchlistener android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

Touchlistener added to viewpager sometimes causes

```
Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mPrivateFlags' on a null object reference in method 'boolean android.view.ViewGroup.resetCancelNextUpFlag(android.view.View)
```

I was rewriting onTouch event and when user slide up it must delete viewpager item.

run this project, slide several times until only 2 images left. Press and keep first image , then slide up second. You get a crash. The solution is to close fragment on another thread.

https://github.com/NurseyitTursunkulov/NPE_resetCancelNextUpFlag_ViewPager